# Python: Adding integer elements of a nested list to a list

Tags: python, dictionary, bioinformatics, nested-lists

So, I have two lists whose integer elements need to be added.

```
nested_lst_1 = [[6],[7],[8,9]]
lst = [1,2,3]
```

I need to add them such that every element in the nested list, will be added to its corresponding integer in 'lst' to obtain another nested list.

```
nested_list_2 = [[6 + 1],[7 + 2],[8 + 3,9 + 3]]
```

or

```
nested_list_2 = [[7],[9],[11,12]]
```

Then, I need to use the integers from nested_list_1 and nested_list_2 as indices to extract a substring from a string.

```
nested_list_1 = [[6],[7],[8,9]]    *obtained above*
nested_list_2 = [[7],[9],[11,12]]  *obtained above*
string = 'AGTCATCGTACGATCATCGAAGCTAGCAGCATGAC'

string[6:7] = 'CG'
string[7:9] = 'GTA'
string[8:11] = 'TACG'
string[9:12] = 'ACGA'
```

Then, I need to create a nested list of the substrings obtained:

```
nested_list_substrings = [['CG'],['GTA'],['TACG','ACGA']]
```

Finally, I need to use these substrings as key values in a dictionary which also possesses keys of type string.

```
keys = ['GG', 'GTT', 'TCGG']
nested_list_substrings = [['CG'],['GTA'],['TACG','ACGA']]

DNA_mutDNA = {'GG':['CG'], 'GTT':['GTA'], 'TCGG':['TACG','ACGA']}
```

I understand that this is a multi-step problem, but if you could assist in any way, I really appreciate it.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Post some code attempt and we'll guide you to the right way.

Comment: `string[6:7] == 'C'` not `'CG'`

Comment: Well, I know how to create a dictionary given two lists (for the last part). The problem is working with nested lists. I am having difficulty creating code that will access elements in a nested list so I could add them respectively with elements in 'lst' (the first step).  If I had two normal lists, I would be able to finish the problem, but I can't because I do not know how to manipulate this data structure for the next steps.

Comment: `keys` list is defined, not computed, am I right?

Comment: Do you _really_ need `nested_list_2`, or are you just building it as an intermediate step towards making the string list?

Comment: ingvar yes you are right keys is already defined

Comment: @PM2Ring I am using nested_list_2 so that I could define the last character of my substring

Comment: `string[6:7] = 'CG'` - do you really want `6:7` (one symbol) or `6:7+1` (two?)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you don't need the intermediate variables, you can do all this with a dictionary comprehension:

```
a = [[6],[7],[8,9]]
b = [1,2,3]
keys = ['GG', 'GTT', 'TCGG']
s = 'AGTCATCGTACGATCATCGAAGCTAGCAGCATGAC'

DNA_mutDNA = {k: [s[start:start+length+1] for start in starts]
               for k, starts, length in zip(keys, a, b)}
```

Comment: Wow! Thanks so much @Stuart, great help!

Answer (score 1):

You can produce the substring list directly with a nested list comprehension, `nested_lst_2` isn't necessary.

```
nested_lst_1 = [[6],[7],[8,9]]
lst = [1,2,3]
string = 'AGTCATCGTACGATCATCGAAGCTAGCAGCATGAC'
keys = ['GG', 'GTT', 'TCGG']

substrings = [[string[v:i+v+1] for v in u] for i, u in zip(lst, nested_lst_1)]
print(substrings)

DNA_mutDNA = dict(zip(keys, substrings))
print(DNA_mutDNA)
```

**output**

```
[['CG'], ['GTA'], ['TACG', 'ACGA']]
{'GG': ['CG'], 'GTT': ['GTA'], 'TCGG': ['TACG', 'ACGA']}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In[2]: nested_lst_1 = [[6],[7],[8,9]]
  ...: lst = [1,2,3]
  ...: string = 'AGTCATCGTACGATCATCGAAGCTAGCAGCATGAC'
  ...: keys = ['GG', 'GTT', 'TCGG']
In[3]: nested_lst_2 = [[elem + b for elem in a] for a, b in zip(nested_lst_1, lst)]
In[4]: nested_list_substrings = []
  ...: for a, b in zip(nested_lst_1, nested_lst_2):
  ...:     nested_list_substrings.append([string[c:d + 1] for c, d in zip(a, b)])
  ...: 
In[5]: {k: v for k, v in zip(keys, nested_list_substrings)}
Out[5]: {'GG': ['CG'], 'GTT': ['GTA'], 'TCGG': ['TACG', 'ACGA']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely not the most readable way to do it, here is a bit of functional style fun:

```
nested_lst_1 = [[6], [7], [8,9]]
lst = [1, 2, 3]
nested_lst_2 = list(map(
    list,
    map(map, map(lambda n: (lambda x: n+x), lst), nested_lst_1)))
nested_lst_2
```

Result looks as expected:

```
[[7], [9], [11, 12]]
```

Then:

```
from itertools import starmap
from operator import itemgetter

make_slices = lambda l1, l2: starmap(slice, zip(l1, map(lambda n: n+1, l2)))
string = 'AGTCATCGTACGATCATCGAAGCTAGCAGCATGAC'
get_slice = lambda s: itemgetter(s)(string)
nested_list_substrings = list(map(
    lambda slices: list(map(get_slice, slices)),
    starmap(make_slices, zip(nested_lst_1, nested_lst_2))))
nested_list_substrings
```

Result:

```
[['CG'], ['GTA'], ['TACG', 'ACGA']]
```

And finally:

```
keys = ['GG', 'GTT', 'TCGG']
DNA_mutDNA = dict(zip(keys, nested_list_substrings))
DNA_mutDNA
```

Final result:

```
{'GG': ['CG'], 'GTT': ['GTA'], 'TCGG': ['TACG', 'ACGA']}
```